# SQL statement timing from MySQL 5.7 client when using a script

Tags: mysql

When I run a SQL statement interactively in a MySQL 5.7 client it tells me how long the query ran:

```
mysql> select now();
--------------
select now()
--------------

+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-03-09 14:27:42 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

In this case it ran for 0.07 seconds.

But when I run the same SQL statement through a script the output does not include the time the statement took.

```
>mysql -f -v --table -u myuser -pmypassword -h myhost mydb < test.sql

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
--------------
select now()
--------------

+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-03-09 14:31:00 |
+---------------------+
```

How can I run a SQL statement from a script and still get back the length of time that it ran using the MySQL 5.7 client?

Thanks!
Bobby

Comment: Does adding more [verbosity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_verbose) `-v` `-v` `-v` `-v` help?

Comment: I thought I had looked at the -v flag but didn't read the manual carefully enough to see that you could have it multiple times. I'm new to mysql. Thanks for saving me time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-vvv` with mysql command.

```
mysql -f -vvv --table -u myuser -pmypassword -h myhost mydb < test.sql

> mysql -vvv < mysql.sql 
--------------
select now()
--------------

+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-03-10 04:08:33 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Bye
```

Hope it will fulfill your requirement :)